# Sortable JS Library: How to combine UL drag and drop with "Multi"? (jsfiddle inc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/nLr39kbr/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/nLr39kbr/)

Been at this for hours but no luck. Trying to combine [Sortable](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/)'s basic UL List (the first example in the demo) with the "Multi" (more than 2 lists) ability (the second example), but in the demo it's using img's intead of li's

Basic UL lists:

```
    <div class="layer">
        <ul id="foo" class="block__list block__list_tags">
            <li>1111</li>
            <li>2222</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="layer">         
        <ul id="bar" class="block__list block__list_words">
            <li>444</li>
            <li>555</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Multi connected lists:

```
        <div class="layer tile">
            <div class="tile__name">Group A</div>
            <div class="tile__list">
                <img src="st/face-01.jpg"/>
                <img src="st/face-02.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="layer tile"  >
            <div class="tile__name">Group B</div>
            <div class="tile__list">
                <img src="st/face-05.jpg"/>
                <img src="st/face-06.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="layer tile">
            <div class="tile__name">Group D</div>
            <div class="tile__list">
                <img src="st/face-08.jpg"/>
                <img src="st/face-09.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle and post the link, so we can take a look and play around with the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nLr39kbr/1/